# Lock file in c# and later, in another thread unlock it?

Tags: c#, file, locking

I understand the the following code coulde be used to lock a file:

```
using (FileStream fs = 
         File.Open("MyFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
   // use fs
}
```

However, I have an application based on actions which runs in different threads. So I want to lock a file first, exit that thread, and then later (maybe hours later) unlock the file. Is this possible?

Comment: Something somewhere will need to keep the file open to do that. Doesn't have to be the same thread (since you can pass FileStream between threads), but something must keep a reference to the FileStream to keep it open.

Comment: Ok thanks, I could work with that, storing the reference in a static object. Just wondered if there was any generic Lock/Unlock method.

Comment: If its a file used by ur app only, maybe it can be easier/ nicer to simulate a lock, by just using a boolean flag?